# css footer image will not display

Tags: html, css

my css footer file as follows

```
body {
    background:url(wood1.jpg) repeat;
}  

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
    border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow:inset 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3),inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25),inset 0 -15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
} 

#footer_menu.homeButton {
    border:none;
    background:none;
}

#footer-menu.homeButton a {
    background-image: url("button.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height:70px;
    padding:5px 8px 50px 15px;
    border:none;
    width:70px;
}

#footer_menu.homeButton:hover a {
    background:none;
}

#footer_menu.homeButton a:hover {
    background:url(homebutton2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

And my html file for footer is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is index file for Footer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="footer1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="footer-menu">
            <li class="homeButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run in browser,it will not display home button.And there is a black dot appear in the   footer.please give the solution for this problem.
when,i will give background position top left,it will not move the image.

Comment: I believe your problem lies here: `background-repeat: no-repeat`. But then, I have no idea on the images dimensions (you didn't mention).

Comment: @MelanciaUK Why would that cause it not to display?

Comment: @Ruddy The OP mentioned a `black dot appear in the footer`. If the image dimensions are that small, I believe they want it to be repeated across.

Comment: @MelanciaUK The black dot would be the `<li>`.

Comment: @Ruddy good point. LOL Just ignore my comment then.

Comment: @MelanciaUK The answer is because there is no space between the class's in the `CSS` as someone said below. :)

Comment: @Ruddy Yes! And I upvoted the answer. Well spotted. :)

Comment: please format your code from now on. I did it this time.

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS seletor is:

```
#footer_menu.homeButton
```

This is an item with the id of footer_menu AND the class of homeButton.
If its a child element then you should add a space:

```
#footer_menu .homeButton
```

This is an item with the id of #footer_menu and a child with a class of homeButton

Comment: Correct. This is what would be causing it. None of the `CSS` is reaching the target because there is no space between the classes. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Give below css for removing dot

```
ul {
    list-style: none
    }
```

Check this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dcFAi)

as suggested above add space between selector.

```
#footer_menu .homeButton
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to understand class and id rules and how to call theme in your style , if you want to style your footer in this specific example , you have to command it like this :

```
#footer{ your codes are here }
```

and if you want to style another id in your div , you gotta know that `footer-menu`is a child for `#footer`and must be command like this

```
#footer > #footer-menu { your codes are here }
```

and if you want to style specific id and class this is it's style
`#iD > .class { your codes are here }`
well take a look at this [Css footer not showing up](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/zmBG7/)

and i think you gotta make 
`z-index = 1`